# Cyclic amalgamation of solvable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Given a nonempty set of groups $\{G_\lambda|\lambda \in \Lambda\}$ together with a group $H$ which
is isomorphic with a subgroup $H_\lambda$ of $G_\lambda$ by means of monomorphism $\phi_\lambda: H \to G_\lambda$. There is a frequently used term known as the free product of the $G_\lambda$'s with the amalgamated subgroup $H$. Roughly speaking, this is the largest
group generated by the $G_\lambda$'s in which the subgroups $H_\lambda$ are identified with $H$ by $\phi_\lambda$. Such groups are known as *generalized free products*.

My question concerns a result proved by [Kahorbaei and Majewicz](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00990487/document) claiming the following.
[image]
[image]

> **Question**. I'm uncertain about this proof. Why must the cosets $a\delta_{m+1}A$ and $b\delta_{n+1}B$ have the same order in its respective factor group? I'm worried about the infinite cyclic subgroup.

Here is the definition for [residually solvable group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Residually_solvable_group).

> **Edit:** I suspect there are counterexamples to the statement (or maybe I misunderstood their definition of the generalized free product). It seems that it requires extra hypothesis such as cosets of same order or something called compatible filtration in Proposition 1 of [Baumslag](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1971-156-00/S0002-9947-1971-0274562-8/S0002-9947-1971-0274562-8.pdf) (as suggested by Carl-Fredrik Nyberg Brodda).

Comment: Related: Proposition 1 of [this paper by Baumslag](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1995606.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A6ed3ab40c0c730a78c7067035942cc01).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements do not have to have the same order it would seem.  According to the paper [ON TORSION-FREE METABELIAN GROUPS WITH COMMUTATOR QUOTIENTS OF PRIME EXPONENT](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218196799000308)  by Narain Gupta and Said Sidki there  are torsion-free metabelian groups whose commutator quotients are nontrivial with prime exponent for any odd prime $p$. So choosing examples $A$ and $B$ with different primes, say $3$ and $5$, gives infinite order elements $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ (not in the commutator subgroup) that have orders $3$ and $5$, respectively, modulo the commutator subgroup.

Comment: Thanks. Will that affect their proof? Maybe I’m missing something.

Comment: I think they would need to add the hypothesis that those two cosets have the same order for the proof to work.  If the orders are not equal the central product I think can't be formed so far as I know.

Comment: I didn't read the whole paper. Maybe they have some reduction to when the orders are equal